# Convert integers into their order of appearance

Tags: r

I would like to change a vector of integers into their order of appearance.

Suppose I have this vector:

```
c(3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1)
```

The integer 3 appears first, so it should be 1.

The integer 2 appears second, so it should be 2. And so on.

The desired outcome:

```
1 2 1 3 3 4 4 2 6
```

Comment: Try also `match(x, unique(x))`

Answer (score 2):

You can coerce to `factor` with `unique` values as levels.

```
as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x)))
# [1] 1 2 1 3 3 4 4 2 5
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use match function to find the order of appearance of unique values:

```
x <- c(3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1) 
match(x, unique(x))
[1] 1 2 1 3 3 4 4 2 5
```

Comment: Both this solution and the one from jay.sf work perfectly. Note however that this one is noticeably faster (`plot(microbenchmark::microbenchmark(as.numeric(factor(x, levels=unique(x))), match(x, unique(x))))`)!